# How to set character used as decimal point in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, decimal, point

I'm making a quick program in C# and I have a problem with character used as decimal point. Right now, I need to use

> ,

but I want to be able to use

> .

or even better, both.

I'm looking for some short and easy solution, because the whole program is a hack, and I doubt that, except for this one point, I'll ever need to make it look better.

Here's one of the problematic pieces of code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double Ri, B, R, T;            
            Ri = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            B = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            R = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);

            T = B / Math.Log(R*1000 / Ri, Math.Exp(1)) - 273.15;
            textBox5.Text = T.ToString();

        }
```

I'm using automatically generated button and I just plaed the formula I need to have calculated into it. As you can see, right now I'm using Convert.ToDouble, for conversion. Are there any better ways to do it? I'd also like, if possible, to avoid going through the string and looking for dots and commas and fixing them by hand.

I also have a feeling that the problem is related to locale setting on my system, but I'd rather not change it at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the comma, change your last line to:

```
textBox5.Text = T.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
```

For the period, use this:

```
textBox5.Text = T.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); 
// or use any "normal" country
```

And to do the reverse (parse the original value in the text box), do this for the comma:

```
double d = double.Parse(textBox5.Text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
```

And this for the period:

```
double d = double.Parse(textBox5.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: Actually, I need it with Convert.ToDouble. How would I use it with that?

Comment: I was just getting to that. :)  `double.parse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: You could also use multiple `double.tryParse` calls in case you're not sure how users will enter numbers.

Comment: Is there any way to permanently set your IDE (VS) to read dot as the separator instead of comma?

Comment: @ryuji89: you mean so that you can type numbers in your code with the separators you're used to using? Beats me - I'm from a "normal" country, so I've never had to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        float Ri, B, R, T;
        Ri = float.Parse((String.Format("{0:0.00}",textBox2.Text)));
        B = float.Parse((String.Format("{0:0.00}",textBox3.Text))));
        R = float.Parse((String.Format("{0:0.00}", textBox6.Text)));

        T = B / Math.Log(R * 1000 / Ri, Math.Exp(1)) - 273.15;
        textBox5.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}",T);
```